# PictureBox skewed images

Tags: c#

I am loading multiple images into a picturebox one at a time. Each time the image is loaded in using code like this:

```
        pBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(450, 450);

        pBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;


        pBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        pBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        pBox1.Image = (Image)image;
        pBox1.Refresh();
```

Most images that have the same height as width show up fine, however images that have different heights and weights are skewed. How would I handle images like this to show up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `Zoom` for `PictureBoxSizeMode`. That will uniformly stretch the image:

```
pBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Answer (score 1):

well for one you first set sizemode to CenterImage then set it to StretchImage overwriting what has been first set. but i would set it to zoom.